# How to change logging details in W2008R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, logging, windows-event-log

Is there a way to change what OS is logging in the Event Log?

For example I see "The system time has changed" events in numbers but I dont want them (I have time sync every too often and it is perfectly **by design**).

I dont want to stop time sync. I want to make Windows not logging it. **Is there a way to pick the events I want in the log?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like syslog, the amount of data sent to the log is controlled by the individual app or service, not the log system itself.  You can use filters and subscriptions to reduce the amount of log data you see.  To this end, MS Added the Administrative Events log (look under Event log, Custom views) which is a built in filtered view. You can create your own favorite views to accomplish what you want